# .py to only one .exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, converters

I know that `pyinstaller` can convert `.py` file into `.exe`, but at the same time you will have some folders, so without them your `.exe` file will not work. Is it possible to convert `.py` file into only one `.exe` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) for more advanced conversion settings:

```
$ pip install auto-py-to-exe
$ auto-py-to-exe
```

Then a window will open and you are going to be able to convert your file.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the below command line is if

1. you want to make it a onefile
2. if you want to get rid of the console
3. if there are any external data(png files, the directory is relative to your main)

`pyinstaller  --noconsole --onefile --add-data="icon.png;." main.py`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You need to add the `--onefile` argument.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-F

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download) as described in this [tutorial](https://mounirboulwafa.medium.com/creating-a-single-executable-file-exe-from-a-python-program-abda6a41f74f).

Essential, zip the output you get from `pyinstaller`, and then run the NSIS GUI to configure and build your standalone .exe.